# Does Bootstrap 5 have on hover and on focus classes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I would like to know if Bootstrap 5 have on hover and on focus utility classes.
I went trought the documentation, and could find them. Maybe I didnt look hard enough.

I was told I could simplify the below with bootstrap classes:

```
.edit:hover {
  background: none;
}

.edit:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Will someone let me know if such a thing is possible or not?

Comment: your solution seems to be good, there is no built-in classes